# issue to populate an array of strings or array of char*

Tags: c++, arrays, string

very basic C++ question. Looks I m really rusted there...
All I want to do is to read an array of X strings from a file and create an array of X vertical strings of the horizontal strings.
IE :
file contains:

```
azert
qsdfg
wxcvb
poiuy
mlkjh
```

I want to create a string array containing:

```
aqwpm
zsxol
edcol
rfvuj
tgbyh
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
[bad code]
const int SIZE = 37;
    std::string table_h[SIZE];
    std::string table_v[SIZE];

int i = 0;
    while (source >> table_h[i])    //,sizeof    table_h[i]
    {
        for (int j = 0; j< SIZE; j++)
        {
            table_v[j][i] = table_h[i][j];
        }
        i++;
    }
```

-> works fine for the first line, breaks when i=1. I don't understand what.
I noticed that although     `table_v[0][0] = 'f';` works fine.
Both  `table_v[0][36] = 'f';` and  `table_h[0].at(36);`  break.

With `char *` (which was my first idea),

```
char * table_h[SIZE];
char * table_v[SIZE];
```

something like

```
table_v[0][0] = 'f';
```

immediately breaks.
I suppose I need to allocate memory or initialize something first??

Thx in advance.

Comment: If it is a C++ question, you should probably remove the C tag. A C++ solution would most likely not be valid C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the size of strings before using `operator []` to access them. Resize of `table_h` is optional, but you definitely have to resize `table_v`.

```
    const int SIZE = 37;
    std::string table_h[SIZE];
    std::string table_v[SIZE];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
    {
        table_h[i].resize(SIZE);
        table_v[i].resize(SIZE);
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (source >> table_h[i])
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        {
            table_v[j][i] = table_h[i][j];
        }
        i++;
    }
```

See the [working example](https://ideone.com/97CAle).

In my opinion, if you know the size of a strings, resizing is better than appending. It can save some memory re-allocations, and IMHO it is simply nicer solution.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the `table_v[j]` is an empty string.

The string needs to allocate space for the characters. This is not done by the index operators, i.e.

```
table_v[j][9] = 'a';
```

assumes enough space is allocated for `table_v[j]`.

You can do `append` to your string to add to the initially empty string. Append does not take chars though, so instead of using index of `table_h[i][j]` you can use `substr`.

```
std::string to_append = table_j[i].substr(j, 1)
table[j].append(to_append);
```

This also relieves you of the `i` counter.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how it can be done

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <numeric>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::string> v1 = 
    { 
        "azert", "qsdfg", "wxcvb", "poiuy", "mlkjh"
    };

    for ( const std::string &s : v1 ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto max_size = std::accumulate( v1.begin(), v1.end(), 
                                     size_t( 0 ),
                                     []( size_t acc, const std::string &s ) 
                                     {
                                        return acc < s.size() ? s.size() : acc;
                                     } );

    std::vector<std::string> v2( max_size );

    for ( const std::string &s : v1 )
    {
        for ( std::string::size_type i = 0; i < s.size(); i++ )
        {
            v2[i].push_back( s[i] );
        }
    }

    for ( const std::string &s : v2 ) std::cout << s << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
azert qsdfg wxcvb poiuy mlkjh 
aqwpm zsxol edcik rfvuj tgbyh
```

As for your code than these statements

```
std::string table_h[SIZE];
std::string table_v[SIZE];
```

defined two arrays of empty strings. So you may not apply the subscript opertaor to an empty string. You could use for example member function push_back

```
    for (int j = 0; j< SIZE; j++)
    {
        table_v[j].push_back( table_h[i][j] ); 
    }
```